# Enum identical (different languages) classes

Tags: java

I would like to write enum which will contain months names in two languages (or more) eg. January in English and something in other languages. Do I have to create two identical enums which will have only name field different? I can't extend enums so I doesn't have any idea how to do it other way...

Answer (score 2):

How about creating an enumeration that has a way of giving a language specific text of the month?

```
public enum Month {

 JAN("january","..."),
 FEB("february","..."),
 MAR("march","..."),
 APR("april","...");

 Month(String english, String spanish){
      this.english=english;
      this.spanish = spanish;
 }
 protected String english;
 protected String spanish;

 public String getEnglish() {
       return this.english;
 }

 public String getSpanish() {
       return this.spanish;
 }
}
```

An alternative would be to provide a plain enumeration of the months and then a factory method to create language specific text values. This solution is more extensible as it allows you to add new languages without changing the enumeration signature.

```
public enum Month {

  JAN,
  FEB,
  MAR,
  APR,
  ....
}


public interface MonthConverter {
    public String toText(Month value);
}

public class MonthEnglish implements MonthConverter {
    @Override
    public String toText(Month value) { ... }
}
public class MonthSpanish implements MonthConverter {
    @Override
    public String toText(Month value) { ... }
}
```

Comment: my bad, copied code without adapting the constructor ... it compiles now in my IDE

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to write enum which will contain months names in two
>   languages (or more) eg. January in English and something in other
>   languages.

I would suggest you don't do that. Why? Because if you want to extends your application and add support for a new language you will have to change the code for enum and new methods for the new language.

You can use the Strategy pattern to resolve this problem.
You will have "regular" `enum` for months

```
enum Month {
    JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC;
}
```

And the interface for getting month name

```
interface MonthNames {
    public String getMonthName(Month month);
}
```

To get name month in English this is the implementation of the interface

```
class EnglishMonthNames implements MonthNames {
    private static Map<Month, String> monthNames = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        monthNames.put(Month.JAN, "January");
        monthNames.put(Month.FEB, "February");
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public String getMonthName(Month month) {
        return monthNames.get(month);
    }

}
```

To add support for Spanish

```
class SpanishMontNames implements MonthNames {
    private static Map<Month, String> monthNames = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        monthNames.put(Month.JAN, "Enero");
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public String getMonthName(Month month) {
        return monthNames.get(month);
    }

}
```

Example of usage

```
public class MonthDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnglishMonthNames english = new EnglishMonthNames();
        System.out.println("The first month in year is " + english.getMonthName(Month.JAN));

        SpanishMontNames spanish = new SpanishMontNames();
        System.out.println("Spanish name for January is " + spanish.getMonthName(Month.JAN));
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a spelling error in your example, `SpanishMontNames`.

Comment: Would it make sense for the map to be unmodifiable?

Comment: Consider how you might better adhere to the Law of Demeter. There is a violation in the demo needing to know the methods of the `XxxMonthNames` types and about the enum, and the `XxxMonthNames` types also needing to know about the enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the enum values with one of the languages and then provide the other language as a field:

```
public enum Month {
    JANUARY("Enero", "Gennaio");

    private String spanishMonth, italianMonth;

    private Month(String spanishMonth, String italianMonth) {
        this.spanishMonth = spanishMonth;
        this.italianMonth = italianMonth;
    }

    public String getSpanishMonth() {
        return spanishMonth;
    }

    public String getItalianMonth() {
        return italianMonth;
    }
}
```

If you want to search by the other language, simply create a `Map` to store them by value:

```
private static final Map<String, Month> MONTHS = new HashMap<>();

static {
    Arrays.stream(values()).forEach(month -> {
        MONTHS.put(month.getSpanishMonth(), month);
        MONTHS.put(month.getItalianMonth(), month);
    }
});

public static Month monthForName(String name) {
    return MONTHS.get(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hard code the languages you'll have a devil of a time expanding the language selection. You could add a method to the enum to do the translation from the canonical representation, something like

```
public String translate(Language language);
```

Then only the `Language` implementation need have logic to translate a `Month` instance, perhaps based on its canonical string through a service call to a translator, or via the sort of `Map` lookup others have suggested. Externalizing the translation satisfies the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP), follows programming to the interface, and makes it easier to inject different implementations.

`Language` might be defined as

```
public interface Language {
  String translate(String value);
}

public class FrenchMonths implements Language {
  private static final Map<String, String> months;
  static {
    Map<String, String> mons = new HashMap<>();
    mons.put(Month.JANUARY.toString(), "Janvier);
    ...
    months = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mons);
  }
  @Override public String translate(String translate) {
    return months.get(translate);
  }
}
```

The enum would have

```
public String translate(Language language) {
  return language.translate(toString());
}
```

You could use it like

```
JANUARY.translate(new FrenchMonths());
```

or

```
getMonth().translate(getLanguage());
```

There are many other ways. The aim is to make it simple to use and extend.